# call_user_func_array error parsing objects

Tags: php, oop

Hello i have the following piece of code and i'm having the following error:
Any ideas how to do it?

```
Argument 1 passed to Invoice\Invoice::__construct() must be an instance of Invoice\Data, none given, called in /Template.php on line 55 and defined

    if(!empty($this->class1) && !empty($this->class2))
    {
        if(!empty($this->params))
            call_user_func_array(array(new $this->class(new $this->class1, new $this->class2), $this->method), $this->params);
        else
            call_user_func(new $this->class(new $this->class1, new $this->class2), $this->method); // line 55
    }
    else
    {
        if(!empty($this->params))
            call_user_func_array(array(new $this->class, $this->method), $this->params);
        else
            call_user_func(array(new $this->class, $this->method));  
    }
```

New Update On Code:

```
if(!empty($this->model) && !empty($this->view))
{
    if(!empty($this->params))
    {
        call_user_func_array(array(new $this->view(new $this->controller, new $this->model), $this->action), $this->params);
    }
    else
    {
        call_user_func(new $this->view(new $this->controller(new $this->model), new $this->model), $this->action);
    }
}
else
{
    if(!empty($this->params))
    {
        call_user_func_array(array(new $this->controller, $this->action), $this->params);
    }
    else
    {
        call_user_func(array(new $this->controller, $this->action));
    } 
}
```

I'm using [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) insde of controller model and view and parsing the right args to each of the vars in the above code and defined the right type hints in each of the classes.
What i want to achieve with the above code is:

```
$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($controller, $model);
```

Error I'm Having:

```
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given
```

Update
Forgot to post the exact line where i'm having that error

```
call_user_func(new $this->view(new $this->controller(new $this->model), new $this->model), $this->action);
```

Comment: Can you post a code of Invoice class?

Comment: Invoice class is just a controller nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->class` is `Invoice\Invoice`, and the constructor of that class takes a parameter of type `Invoice\Data`.

The construct `new $className` does not pass parameters to the constructor, so that particular constructor cannot run.

Using something like `new $className(new \Invoice\Data())` would have worked, but of course only in the case where you are constructing an `Invoice` -- it's useless in the general case.

In general, when you are dynamically constructing objects there are two ways you can go:

**The easy way**.

You need to assume something about the signature of the constructor (e.g. "it must have no required parameters"), and you can hardcode this assumption using constructs such as `new $className()`.

**The hard way**.

You need to use reflection to determine what parameters the constructor takes. That's a little involved and it only works for type-hinted parameters, but it's actually the easy part. The hard part is finding appropriate instances to pass when you call the constructor.

Comment: well the entire idea here is to do this:
$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($controller, $model);
But using call_user_func_array

Comment: Well i'm using type hinted params inside the classes, and i i'm passing to the call_user_func_array exactly the class that i want to load.. name everything.

Comment: @Bogdan: The problem is not with `call_user_func_array` -- which **can not** create new objects; it's with `new $this->class` or `new $this->class1` or one of those in general.

Comment: seems so. yet what i pass is not empty already checked

Comment: Update: been changing the code a little bit and i'm closer to fixing the problem now says that i parsed a string instead of parsing an instance of the class
Forgot to up new in front.

Comment: @Bogdan: You should point out exactly which line we are talking about and what the values for all variables mentioned in that line are. After doing this the answer will become obvious.

Comment: Just a minute i'll post new code.